# python Portrait and landscape page in pdf

Tags: python, pdf, glob, fpdf, img2pdf

I am new to python. I want to generate a pdf with 3 images, 1 image is a portrait, the second image is a landscape and the third image is a portrait again. But it seems the code below cannot handle this situation, am I missing anything?

```py
images = []
images = glob.glob(Outpath + "/IMG/*.jpg" ,recursive=False)

pdf = FPDF()

for x in range(len(images)):
    print(images[x] + ' at x = ' + str(x))

    #pdf.add_page()
    if width > height:
        pdf.add_page(orientation='L')
        pdf.image(images[x],x=0,y=0,h=210,w=297)
    elif width < height:
        pdf.add_page(orientation='P')
        pdf.image(images[x],x=0,y=0,h=297,w=210)

pdf.output(Outpath + "/IMG/IO.pdf", "F")
```

Comment: Create only one object if you want one PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new object in each iteration.

Create a single variable once and use that in future iterations as below:

```
import glob
from fpdf import FPDF

images = []
images = glob.glob(Outpath + "/IMG/*.jpg" ,recursive=False)

pdf = FPDF()

for x in range(len(images)):

    im_int = Image.open(images[x])
    width = im_int.width
    height = im_int.height
    if width > height:
        pdf.add_page(orientation='L')
        pdf.image(images[x],x=0,y=0,h=210,w=297)
    else:
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(images[x],x=0,y=0,h=297,w=210)

pdf.output(Outpath + "/IMG/IO.pdf", "F")
```

Comment: Thanks, I can now generate 3 pages.
But is there any way can create a pdf file with the 1 page is a portrait, the second page is a landscape and the third page is a portrait again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware about changing the page style dynamically.

Comment: Nevermind, thx for your help, I will post the solution if I solve it.

Comment: I just solved the problem, I have uploaded the code for your reference

Comment: Awesome, I also found the documentation here: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_page/index.html and updated the code. Please check if that is what you needed.

Comment: @IgnatiusNG, I have updated the code with your edits, please consider the accepting the changes if it works so that the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: Thx for the help~